# Как передавать данные из node.js в php

Tags: node.js, comet, php

Делаем игру для контакта. PHP+flash. А также node.js в качестве comet-сервера для чата и прочего. Для передачи данных я нашел 3 варианта: 
1. Делать http запрос от node.js к php 
2. Запустить отдельный процесс в виде php скрипта, который будет слушать данные либо по tcp-сокету либо через redis pub/sub. Причем в этом скрипте еще нужно будет инициировать фреймворк, чтобы пользоваться уже существующей архитектурой моделей. 
3. Так же как и во 2 варианте, только запускать php-скрипт по cron`у.
Вопрос в том, какой лучше метод выбрать, или может есть еще какие?

Comment: @s-prosvirnin, а в чем, вопрос-то? вы ведь сами на него и ответили, перечислив разные способы

Comment: вопрос именно в выборе подходящего способа. меня смущает, например, что http запрос из node.js в php, бужет несколько медленнее, чем 2 и 3 вариант

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS разве не пойдет целиком для этих целей? Я вот на php сделал игру, держит 20 коннектов только.
[Сервер на php не держит больше 20 активных игроков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364726/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-20-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Мне посоветовали целиком перейти на Node.js.

Comment: Основа работы с данными написана на php. Nodejs используется только в качестве comet-сервера, т.к. я не особо знаю nodejs, только азы. Но, можно и целиком использовать Nodejs.

Comment: У меня сейчас всё написано на php. Предлагаю объединиться и делиться советами при изучении nodejs(открыл в профайле ссылку на себя вконтакте). ИМХО лучше не мудрить с прослойками.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP-CLI](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php) Не пойдёт?

Comment: хм, может я не понимаю, но, как можно из node.js запустить php скрипт?

Comment: С node.js не работал, но там же есть что-то вроде exec() или system()? Или уже предложенный cron.

Comment: конечно, можно, node.js полноценный язык программирования. например, так

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var cp = spawn('ping', ['-n', '-W 1', '-c 4', 'yandex.ru']);

    var stdout = '';

    cp.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        stdout += data;
    });

Comment: очень интересно, но, ведь придется попрощаться с масштабируемостью...

Comment: @s-prosvirnin, к сожалению, опыта масштабирования у меня нет, но Redis последних версий кластеризацию [поддерживает][1]

 [1]:http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: про масштабируемость я имел в виду, когда вы говорили про вызов php-скрипта из nodejs.
-> но я бы порекомендовал воспользоваться прослойкой в виде redis - не нужно будет писать велосипед для обработки очередей.
а как можно это сделать, если нет php скрипта, который бы принимал данные?

Comment: @s-prosvirnin, я вам написал пример, как запускать шелл-команды. а потом оговорился, что лучше не делать этого, а пользоваться возможностями Redis, когда php-скрипт подписывается на каналы в Redis. По крайней мере я это хотел сказать :)

Comment: я так и понял. но, как можно подписаться на каналы Redis, если у нас нет php-скрипта в памяти. я как раз и хочу использовать pub/sub Redis`a, но ведь нужен php-скрипт, который будет висеть и принимать данные или делать  это через http-запрос. или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Все зависит от того, в какую сторону передавать данные планируется. Если от клиента к php-скрипту, то стек получается такой:

клиент -> node.js -> redis-publish -> REDIS <- redis-subscribe <- php

В таком варианте php-скрипту придется висеть постоянно, подписавшись на каналы. Но вы же PHP обозначили в задаче. Если есть возможность, можете вообще отказаться от него, выполняя все задачи на node.js.